# How to install less on my localhost php server

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, less, npm

according to the site lesscss.org all I need to do is to write this line:

```
$ npm install less
```

inside my npm.

I went to the npm site: https://github.com/isaacs/npm

and downloaded the project - I didn't understand what do I need to do with it. installed node.js because somewhere it was written to install it. none of this helped.

It clicked node.exe - it opened for me a console: I tries to write there:

```
$ npm install less
```

but that didnt do anything.

**I am obviously missing something, can anyone tell me how do I work with node.js , npm , and how to get LESS parser on my server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run npm on a regular command line, not a node console.

… and don't write the `$`, that signifies the prompt, not something you should type.